# Multiplying a string containing numbers with another string containing same?

Tags: java, string

Suppose I have a string

`String string = "1.18";`

I want to multiply the above string with another string that is

```
String f1= "2.54";
```

What would I have to do to multiply these two values? I looked this up online and came across a function called `Integer.ParseInt()` that converts the string to it's numerical values, so i tried

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(string) * Integer.parseInt(f1));
```

It doesn't work. I want to know what am I doing wrong. What's the proper way of doing it? I would find it very helpful if someone could help me understand, thanks!

Comment: They aren't _integral types_, but _float types_. So better do `Double.parseDouble(...)`! Additionally, saying "it doesn't work" is not an appropriate problem description.

Comment: It showed Exception in thread... and thanks, using Double.parseDouble(...) solved the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Double.parseDouble(string)`

Comment: Got it, thanks! I didn't know there was another class for double/float data types

Answer (score 2):

`Integer` is not for decimal number. Use `Double.parseDouble()` or use `BigDecimal` type  if you need exact result.

Comment: Got it, thanks! I didn't know there was another class for double/float data types